# jquery - can't get datepicker and login on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui, xmlhttprequest, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm building a website. I have the login javascript working. I want to add a datepicker object from the jquery UI library, which I have downloaded and placed in the root/jqueryUI folder. I've researched multiple ways of finagling this, but I have come up with nothing that seems to work.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jqueryUI/jquery-ui.js">
var $113 = jQuery.noConflict();  
$113( function() {
$113( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login-trigger').click(function(){
$(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass('active');          

if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
  else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
})
});
```

The only thing I can think that would cause this to error out is that I am currently loading the 'Content' DIV tag with the response from a xmlhttp request

**Load example:**

```
function loadContent(Fname) 
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else 
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}   
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
    {
        document.getElementById('Content').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "../php/actions.php?F=" + Fname, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The pulled information is as follows (php)

(PHP) **actions.php**

```
if($function =='writeNews')
{
print("
....
<div id='newsPubDate'><strong>Date to Publish:</strong><input type='text' id='datePicker'></div>
</div>");
}
```

TL;DR - I need a way for javascript to apply itself to a div tag that gets called. A simple datepicker object that gets called to write a news post (on the same page). I could program individual pages or reload the page, I guess, but I wonder if there's a way to pull this off without refreshing the page every time someone wants to do a basic admin function.

Answer (score 0):

When running through the xmlhttprequest, the javascript/jquery will not execute. The simplest way of fixing this was to remove the xmhttprequest loader and simply use a GET method on a form to reload the page with the appropriate code ready for it.